# Apache Chemistry with https url not correct request

Tags: php, curl, https, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm using Apache Chemistry PHP client with local Alfresco repository with http protocol over 8080 and I can connect to the repo.

However, when I try to use the same library over other Alfresco repository over https protocol (port 8443) I get this exception:

> [26-Jun-2016 01:51:10 Europe/Madrid] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CmisRuntimeException' in /Example/cmis/cmis_repository_wrapper.php:176
>   Stack trace:

```
#0 /Example/cmis/cmis_repository_wrapper.php(210): CMISRepositoryWrapper->convertStatusCode(0, false)
#1 /Example/cmis/cmis_repository_wrapper.php(191): CMISRepositoryWrapper->doGet('http://192.168....')
#2 /Example/cmis/cmis_repository_wrapper.php(128): CMISRepositoryWrapper->connect('http://192.168....', 'angel', '123456', NULL)
#3 /Example/cmis/cmis_service.php(143): CMISRepositoryWrapper->__construct('http://192.168....', 'angel', '123456', NULL, Array)
```

I can see that doGet function use "http" URL but my string connection is with https.

What is the problem? The same code with Alfresco repository over http protocol is correct.

Comment: Have you configured your Alfresco repo to report HTTPS URLs for the external references rather than HTTP ones? As per http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/configure-ssl-prod.html

Comment: I use a docker Alfresco image.

I've found one solution.

If I modify file cmis_repository_wrapper.php, method doRequest and add this:

 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
All go correct. So, I think that the problem is that my test site of alfresco https://..... the certificate is not validate, so it don't work correct.

Comment: Which docker image are you using? (lots of people publish them and they're not all of the same quality!) And how are you configuring it for SSL?

Comment: I use this one https://hub.docker.com/r/pdubois/docker-alfresco/ it's comming with ssl (non validate) certificate. Is very easy to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I use a docker Alfresco image.

I've found one solution.

If I modify file cmis_repository_wrapper.php, method doRequest and add this:

```
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

All go correct. 
So, I think that the problem is that my test site of alfresco https://..... the certificate is not validate, so it don't work correct.